# How to get the url and put them in a text file one line by one line?

Tags: php

supposed there is a variable named:

```
src="http://www.test.com/1455/"||src="http://www.test.com/image/1456/"||
```

now i want to get the url part `http://www.test.com/1455/`.

the following is my code.but it doesn't work.

```
$url = 'src="http://www.test.com/1455/"||src="http://www.test.com/image/1456/"||';

$a = explode("src=\"",$url); 
$b = explode("||",$a); 
$handle = fopen("output.txt", 'a')) !== FALSE
fwrite($handle2, "{$b[0]}\n");
```

Comment: Use regular expressions to match the patterns and get the array of matching records. http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression something similar to this, of course you can modify this as you needed. This is just an example but it will work for you

```
$url = 'src="http://www.test.com/1455/"||src="http://www.test.com/image/1456/"||';
preg_match_all('/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', $url, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_R($result);
```

it will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.test.com/1455/
            [1] => http://www.test.com/image/1456/
        )

)
```

and write this in text file:

```
$handle = fopen("output.txt", 'a');
foreach($result[0] as $url){
    fwrite($handle, $url."\n");     
}
fclose($handle);
```

more details on regex here http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: i put your code in. it shows Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  thank you

Comment: did you tried to print the extracted result with `print_r($result);`, the warning may be due to empty `$result`

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the more general case. This code converts your string into URL query format and parse it via [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function

```
$url = 'src="http://www.test.com/1455/"||src="http://www.test.com/image/1456/"||var1=aaa||var2=bbb||var2=bbb';
$url = str_replace('||', '&', $url);
$url = preg_replace('/([^\]])=/', '$1[]=', $url);

$params = array();
parse_str($url, $params);

print_r($params);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [src] => Array
        (
            [0] => "http://www.test.com/1455/"
            [1] => "http://www.test.com/image/1456/"
        )

    [var1] => Array
        (
            [0] => aaa
        )

    [var2] => Array
        (
            [0] => bbb
            [1] => bbb
        )

)
```

Then you can do with this array everything you want

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'src="http://www.test.com/1455/"||src="http://www.test.com/image/1456/"||';

$a = explode("||",$url); 

$handle = fopen("output.txt", 'a');
foreach($a as &$val)
{
   $val = str_replace("src=\"","",$val);
   $val  = str_replace("\"","",$val);
   fwrite($handle, "{$val}\r\n");
}
```